# Word 2010 freezes when inserting a document cover - how do I determine the cause of the issue?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, crash, microsoft-word-2010

When I insert certain document covers in Word 2010 (64-bit) the program freezes. I then have to end the process, relaunch Word and then use the recovery version of the document in order to continue working on it.

Strangely, some document covers insert fine - for example, Austin and Contrast. Others cause Word to freeze - for example, Sideline and Stacks.  It seems unusual that the earlier covers to choose from work fine, whilst the later ones do not.

I'd prefer to find a way to remedy the problem, rather than continue to live with it.

How can I determine what is causing the issue? The only information I can see in the Windows Event Viewer is this, but it doesn't mean anything to me:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: AppHangTransient Response: Not
>   available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: WINWORD.EXE P2: 14.0.6129.5000 P3: 5082f340 P4:
>   unknown P5: unknown P6: unknown P7: unknown P8:  P9:  P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> These files may be available here:
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   db33af10-794e-11e2-a6a0-c0cb38bb889f Report Status: 1

I have tried starting Word in Safe Mode, however, cover pages are not available this way. I have also disabled all plugins and templates, to no avail.

Comment: Check the Windows Application and System logs and see if any useful details there as a start

Comment: Try booting up in safe mode and see if you can insert the cover. If it works in safe mode then there might be a shell extension or something else causing the crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, cover pages aren't available in safe mode. I've updated the description to include new information, however.